# Nginx php-fpm optimization in centos 7

Tags: nginx, cloud, php7

My server setup uses cloud azure VMSS.

I have an issue when testing 200 users' requests that produce error 502 and non-HTTP response message connection timed out connect.

Already followed some advice from another website (e.g https://medium.com/@jituboss/nginx-and-php-fpm-optimization-for-high-traffic-web-applications-f790bf1b30fb) credit to the creator, but still produce error.

When I use 2 instances of the server backend and try 200 users, there's no error produced, yet it seems that I can optimize further by using 1 server.

Comment: can you elaborate on your setup and configuration? would be useful for someone to advise you on the nature of the issue.

Comment: post output of nginx error log and `dmesg` right after failing your tests with 502